Infinite loop on pagination with selenium
I have this simple scraping. It's working fine and all, but when gets to pagination, when it goes to the last pagination it goes to an infinite loop. It goes to an infinite loop on the last page:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov  4 21:22:10 2024

@author: user
"""
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
quantidade_2024 = 0
quantidade_2023 = 0
quantidade_2022 = 0
quantidade_2021 = 0
precos = []
tamanhos = []
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    #options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxy}")    
    #options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #options.add_argument("disable-infobars")options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--verbose")
        #options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") 
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")    
data_planilha = []
precos_m2 = []

url_base = "https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/ceara/caucaia/bairros/caucaia/#onde=,Cear%C3%A1,Caucaia,Bairros,Caucaia,,,,BR%3ECeara%3ENULL%3ECaucaia%3EBarrios%3ECaucaia,,,/"
driver.get(url_base)
#driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class = 'header__nav-links']/li[2]/a").click()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
resultados = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class = 'results__main']" )))
quantidade_imoveis = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[@class = 'results-summary__count js-total-records']"))).text
quantidade_imoveis = int(quantidade_imoveis)
print(quantidade_imoveis)


while True:
    time.sleep(1)    
    imoveis = WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'results-list js-results-list']/div")))
    print("entrou")
    for index, value in enumerate(imoveis):
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        imoveis = WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'results-list js-results-list']/div")))
        
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", imoveis[index])
        time.sleep(3)
        
        
        tamanho = imoveis[index].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class = 'property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value property-card__detail-area js-property-card-detail-area']").text
        #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", tamanho)
       # tamanho = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//span[@class = 'property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value property-card__detail-area js-property-card-detail-area']"))).text
        print(tamanho)
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        preco = imoveis[index].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class = 'property-card__price js-property-card-prices js-property-card__price-small']/p").text
        preco_imovel = "".join(re.findall('\d+', preco))
        price = int(preco_imovel)
#        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", preco)
        
        #preco = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//div[@class = 'property-card__price js-property-card-prices js-property-card__price-small']/p"))).text
        size = int(tamanho)
        print(preco_imovel)
        precos.append(int(price))
        tamanhos.append(size)
        preco_m2 = price/size
        print(preco_m2)
        precos_m2.append(preco_m2)
        driver.save_screenshot("VIVAREAL.png")
    try:
        botao_proximo = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@title = 'Próxima página']")))

        if botao_proximo.is_enabled():
            
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', botao_proximo)            
        else:
            break
           
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No more pages available")
        break
tamanho_medio = sum(tamanhos)/quantidade_imoveis
preco_medio_total = sum(precos)/quantidade_imoveis
precos_m2_total = sum(precos_m2)/quantidade_imoveis
data_planilha.append({
        'URL': url_base,
        'Número de anúncios': quantidade_imoveis,
        'Preço Médio': preco_medio_total,
        'Tamanho Médio': tamanho_medio,
        'Preço Médio por m2': precos_m2_total,
        
        })
df_planilha = pd.DataFrame(data_planilha)
df_planilha.to_excel("catalogo_vivareal.xlsx")
driver.quit()
        

in this website the last page button goes like this:
<button class="js-change-page" title="Próxima página" data-page="" data-disabled="">
          Próxima página &gt;        
</button>

data-page is an empty string and there is this data-disabled attribute that doesn't appear on the the other pages that not the last page.

How do you know it goes into an infinite loop?  What actual output do you see?

The is_enabled method is not what you are looking for: the element on the last page doesn't have the disabled attribute, it has the data-disabled attribute (which is probably picked up by the page css to make the button appear disabled).
That is a user-defined data attribute, selenium will not look at it to determine if the button is disabled
instead use
... 
        if botao_proximo.get_attribute("data-disabled") is not None:
            ...

